# How to draw a graph with vertical lines of fixed height at several points

Tags: matlab

Basically, I want to draw a graph whose x axis varies from -10 to 10, and the y axis varies from 0 to 10. The graph has vertical lines of height 4 at x = -1 and x = 1.

(I guess, it is a bar graph with infinitely thin bars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can for example cheat with the `stem` function

```
stem([-1 1],[4 4],'Marker','none');
```

Comment: Thanks. I was doing the same with plot function, but stem looks more useful.

Comment: @user2808118 Only for vertical lines start start from the x-axis.